# Drawing multiple object in view using onDraw android

Tags: java, android, canvas

I'm not working on any project, just simply want to learn how to create simple animation using view onDraw method. So i started with drawing multiple objects on custom view, but my program draws only two of defined object with wrong colors.

This is my simple object class, named Square which extends abstract class AbstractObject which defines properties and methods for square object.

```
    package com.kgkg.animationlearn.myDrawings;
    import android.graphics.Canvas;
    import android.graphics.Paint;
    import android.util.Log;
    import com.kgkg.animationlearn.MainActivity;
    /**
     * Created by Krzysiek on 2016-03-11.
     */
    public class Square extends AbstractShape {
        //****************************************************FIELDS*******************
        private int side;

        //**************************************************CONSTRUCTORS*******************************
        private Square() {}

        public Square(int side) {
            super();
            this.side = side;
        }

        public Square(Paint fillColor, int side) {
            super(fillColor);
            this.side = side;
        }

        public Square(Paint fillColor, int x, int y, int side) {
            super(fillColor, x, y);
            this.side = side;
        }

        public Square(int x, int y, int side) {
            super(x, y);
            this.side = side;
        }

        //************************************************GETTERS AND SETTERS**************************
        public int getSide() {
            return side;
        }

        public void setSide(int side) {
            this.side = side;
        }

        //****************************************************METHODS**********************************

        /**
         * side, canvas and paint fields cannot be null otherwise they will use defaults
         * @param canvas
         */
        @Override
        public void drawOnCanvas(Canvas canvas) {
            if (side > 0 && canvas != null){
                canvas.drawRect(getX(), getY(), side, side, getFillColor());
            } else {
                Log.i(MainActivity.TAG, "Somthing is wrong with your object");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Square object \n Properties: \n side: " + side + "\n fillColor: " + getFillColor() +
                    "\nPosition ( " + getX() + ", " + getY() + ")";
        }
    }
```

AbstractObject class

```
    public abstract class AbstractShape implements IDrawOnCanvas{

        //****************************************************FIELDS***********************************
        private Paint fillColor = new Paint(Color.DKGRAY);
        private int x, y;

        //**************************************************CONSTRUCTORS*******************************
        public AbstractShape() {}

        public AbstractShape(Paint fillColor) {
            this.fillColor = fillColor;
        }

        public AbstractShape(Paint fillColor, int x, int y) {
            this.fillColor = fillColor;
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
        public AbstractShape(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        //************************************************GETTERS AND SETTERS**************************
        public Paint getFillColor() {
            return fillColor;
        }

        public void setFillColor(Paint fillColor) {
            this.fillColor = fillColor;
        }

        public int getX() {
            return x;
        }

        public void setX(int x) {
            this.x = x;
        }

        public int getY() {
            return y;
        }

        public void setY(int y) {
            this.y = y;
        }

        public void setPosition(int x, int y){
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        //****************************************************METHODS**********************************

    }
```

```
Interface IDrawOnCanvas
<pre><code>
package com.kgkg.animationlearn.myDrawings;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
public interface IDrawOnCanvas {
    void drawOnCanvas(Canvas canvas);
}
```

```
View class
<pre><code>
public class myView extends View {

    private boolean toDraw;
    private Square[] objects;

    public myView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public myView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    private void init(){
        toDraw = false;
    }

    public boolean isToDraw() {
        return toDraw;
    }

    public void setToDraw(boolean toDraw) {
        this.toDraw = toDraw;
    }

    public Square[] getObjects() {
        return objects;
    }

    public void setObjects(Square[] objects) {
        this.objects = objects;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (toDraw){
            for (int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++){
                canvas.save();
                Log.i(MainActivity.TAG, "rysownaie + " + objects[i].toString());
                objects[i].drawOnCanvas(canvas);
                canvas.restore();
                invalidate();
            }
        }
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }


}
```

```
MainActivity
<pre><code>
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public final static String TAG = "kgkg";

    RelativeLayout relLayout;
    Button btnTest;
    View myV;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        relLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relLayout);
        btnTest = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        myV = findViewById(R.id.view);
        btnTest.setOnClickListener(c);
    }

    private View.OnClickListener c = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Square[] squares = {new Square(new Paint(Color.RED), 0, 0, 50), new Square(50, 50, 100), new Square(50, 0, 50), new Square(new Paint(Color.CYAN), 150, 150, 130)};
            ((myView)myV).setToDraw(true);
            ((myView) myV).setObjects(squares);
            myV.invalidate();
        }
    };
}
```

It should create four squares on myView with red, cyan and black colors after button's onclick method, but instead it creates only two squares with black color, my question is: what is the problem ? why only two objects are drawn and why they don't have proper colors ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

don't invalidate inside the for loop in your OnDraw function. Also I see no use for save and restore calls.
change this

```
  @Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (toDraw){
        for (int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++){
            canvas.save();
            Log.i(MainActivity.TAG, "rysownaie + " + objects[i].toString());
            objects[i].drawOnCanvas(canvas);
            canvas.restore();
            invalidate();
        }
    }
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

to this

```
 @Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (toDraw){
        for (int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++){
            Log.i(MainActivity.TAG, "rysownaie + " + objects[i].toString());
            objects[i].drawOnCanvas(canvas);
        }
    }
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

Comment: i removed save and restore calls from onDraw method, but still the same effect

Comment: did you also remove the invalidate?

Comment: yes i did, after removing invalidate from onclick method, nothing was drawn

Comment: no don't remove the invalidate from the onclick, remove the invalidate from the onDraw

Comment: my bad of course ivalidate in onDraw, but still no effect, my onDraw method looks now exactly as presented above but i'm still keep going :)